# Where is this AttributeError message implemented in CPython?

Tags: python, attributeerror, cpython, python-internals

I think that the `AttributeError` message in this Python session

```py
>>> class A: pass
... 
>>> A().x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'x'
```

is implemented in the function `_PyObject_GenericGetAttrWithDict` at [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/object.c#L1266-L1270) in CPython:

```c
    if (!suppress) {
        PyErr_Format(PyExc_AttributeError,
                     "'%.50s' object has no attribute '%U'",
                     tp->tp_name, name);
    }
```

However I cannot find where the `AttributeError` message in this Python session

```py
>>> class A: __slots__ = ('x',)
... 
>>> A().x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: x
```

is implemented in CPython. Could you provide a link to the exact lines in the GitHub repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Python/structmember.c#L70-L75):

```c
case T_OBJECT_EX:
    v = *(PyObject **)addr;
    if (v == NULL)
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_AttributeError, l->name);
    Py_XINCREF(v);
    break;
```

That's an excerpt from `PyMember_GetOne`, which is where most of the logic for the [`__get__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/descrobject.c#L159) method of the slot descriptor is implemented.

You might also be interested in how that descriptor gets there. `type.__new__` internally [translates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L2758-L2776) `__slots__` to an array of [`PyMemberDef`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyMemberDef) structs, one of the mechanisms classes written in C use to define access to their internal data. All `PyMemberDef` structs generated this way are marked `T_OBJECT_EX`, meaning they correspond to a `PyObject *` in the instance memory layout, and if the pointer is null, access should raise an AttributeError. `PyType_Ready` then [generates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L5468-L5471) the slot descriptors based on the `PyMemberDef` array.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I was also looking for the implementation of the `AttributeError: x` message raised by `del A().x` and now I am able to find it ([here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.4/Python/structmember.c#L112-L118)).